# Menu showing current page

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I try to make a menu that shows the current page that you are visiting. I use Ajax, so the site does not reload. I would also like to use the parent and children functions. I tried this:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('ul').children('li a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

The first line in the click function schould remove the class "current" from all links, but anyway it does not work

Comment: Paste your HTML and use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to:

`$(this).closest('ul').find('li a').removeClass('current')`

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GPbnE/

Comment: Thanks! But as I said I would like to use the parent and children functions in my script

Comment: Ah, I apologize. To use .parent(), you would have to do .parent().parent() (which you probably know) - or, you'd have to do conditional logic to check if the parent of 'this' is actually the parent you're looking for - and then recurse until you find the acutal parent. Which, when you factor in the extra logic - might make a case for .closest()? I'm curious why you need to use .parent() and .children()?